# Check if record exists on the page

Tags: cypress

I have a page with a few results panels, each panel has its own delete button, once the user clicks the delete button a confirmation modal pops up asking if he wants to delete this record.

I wrote a Cypress test to test the delete process, the test works as expected, the modal pops up, if the user confirm the deletion, the panel gets deleted.

On the test I make sure the correct panel got deleted by checking if its `id` doesn't exist on the page anymore.

```
const deleteResult = action => {
  cy.get('div[data-test="Results"]').should('be.visible');
  let contactID;
  cy.get('div[data-test="Results"]')
    .first()
    .within(() => {
      cy.get('p[data-test="Contact ID"]').then($match => {
        contactID= $match.html();
        cy.get('button[data-test="Delete Contact"]')
          .click()
          .get('div[data-test="Delete Record Modal"]')
          .should('be.visible')
          .get(`button[data-test="${action}"]`)
          .click();
      });
    });
  cy.get('p[data-test="Contact ID"]').each($match => {
    cy.wait(2000);
    if (action === 'Confirm Deletion') {
      cy.wrap($match)
        .invoke('text')
        .should('not.eq', contactID);
    } else {
      cy.wrap($match)
        .invoke('text')
        .should('eq', contactID);
    });
};
```

Now I'm trying to write the test of the other option- a user that cancels the deletion, I need to check if the given `contactID` *does* exist on the page, how can I achieve that?

The code above is not correct, it expects *all* panel to have the given `contactID`.

**Edit:**

```
const deleteResult = action => {
  cy.get('div[data-test="Results"]').should('be.visible');
  let contactID;
  cy.get('div[data-test="Results"]')
    .first()
    .within(() => {
      cy.get('p[data-test="Contact ID"]').then($match => {
        contactID= $match.text();
        cy.get('button[data-test="Delete Contact"]')
          .click()
          .get('div[data-test="Delete Record Modal"]')
          .should('be.visible')
          .get(`button[data-test="${action}"]`)
          .click();
      });
    });
  cy.wait(2000);
  const els = cy.get('p[data-test="Contact ID"]');
  if (action === 'Confirm Deletion') {
    els.each($match => {
      cy.wrap($match)
        .invoke('text')
        .should('not.eq', contactID); //contactID is the actual ids
    });
  } else {
    els.should('contain', contactID); //contactID is undefined
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `if` before your `cy.get`, so your logic is no longer nested inside of the `.each`

```js
const els = cy.get(...)
if (something) {
  cy.then(() => els.should('not.contain', contactID))
} else {
  els.each(...)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason the `each` part works as expected but the `els.should('not.contain', contactID)` is erroring: `expected [ <p>, 2 more... ] to contain undefined` How could it be? Why on the else `contactID` is not `undefined` and on the `if` it is?

Comment: The `contactID` is not `undefined` only within the `each`

Comment: Try `contactID = $match.text()`

Comment: Make sure you're putting the if statement below `const els = cy.get('p[data-test="Contact ID"]')`

Comment: For sure, still `undefined`, I don'g get how could it be, please see my edited question.

Comment: See my edited answer. Commands get enqueued synchronously, so your code that sets contactID is not ran before the command to assert on it is enqueued

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting now a different error: `AssertionError: object tested must be an array, an object, or a string, but undefined given`